# Calculate the given integral using Monte Carlo method

Tags: integration, monte-carlo

approximate the integral using Monte Carlo method.

$\int _{r\in B} \frac{1}{|r-r_0|}dr$ , while $r_0 = (1,1,1)$ and B={(x,y,z): $x>0$,$y>0$,$z>0$,$x+y+z < 1$}.

I'm trying to solve the question ,but I have no clue how to solve it , and I only have seen Monte Carlo's method using uniform distribution , Hints would be amazing.

Comment: Is $|\mathbf{x}|$ the usual distance?

Comment: I believe it means $abs((x-1,y-1,z-1))$ @Snoop

Comment: Check the notation conventions in your reference